# Users don't see the newest version in the Android Play Store when coming from in-app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We have an Android app which checks its own version against our backend on startups. Basically the thinking is that we force our users to use the latest version (or get stuck on the splash screen with a dialog about the update). We use this to redirect the user to the play store (when he clicks on a button on this dialog):

```
startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, parse("market://details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)));
            finish();
```

Problem is, even though we update a version, and it shows up in the play store when we search for our app as the latest, the users clicking on that button see that they use the "latest" version (which is the previous version in reality).

So basically:

1. user has version 1.0 installed
2. we update to version 1.1, and set backend to 1.1 as minimum version
3. app on start checks the backend, and shows the update dialog (since its version is outdated)
4. user clicks on update dialog, goes to the play store, but the store shows that the current version is 1.0
5. if you SEARCH for our app normally, you see the newest version is 1.1

This creates a lot of problems for us because the user basically cannot use the app and most does not know the difference above (i.e. they wont search for the app manually)

What causes the isse here? Anyone had similar problems? Is it some form of caching? Should we use a different link format?

Any input is appreciated

Comment: What guarantees you that when you push an update to the Store it is globally available at the same time? Play Store app caches the latest version, it checks new versions every night (if you activate automatic updates) or when you force it manually. Have you considered in-app updates? https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java

Answer (score 0):

Its obviously cache issue. I think you have to more control on backend version , then the **update dialog** would not make your app unusable to users . The idea you can apply -

1. Create a secret [gist](https://gist.github.com/) named `version.json` and give value

   ```
    {
    "versioncode": "1"
    }
   ```

for example "1" is version code of your app.

How to get link - `https://gist.github.com/[gist_user]/[gist_id]/raw/[file_name]`

for example `https://gist.github.com/zahidbd2/be18d53053d23759ecb923fd84ddc23f/raw/version.json`

*You have to edit/update the value of this json after every app publish/release .
And keep in mind that you have to wait few hours or a day to avoid cache problem of playStore . Manually check that your app live in Play store then update the gist .*

**versioncode value of version.json would be the latest version code of your app.**

2. In client side we will retrieve the version code from gist json then compare with with old version code on device by `packageInfo.versionCode`

if oldVersion < curLiveVersion then **update dialog** would show otherwise not . So the app always be usable and users will see Update button in Playstore (cache issue solved). If users try to to ignore the update they would not be use the app until update .

So I combined all in one method , you can check this . Dependency used `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'`

```
 public void updateCheck() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    okhttp3.Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://gist.github.com/zahidbd2/be18d53053d23759ecb923fd84ddc23f/raw/version.json")
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.i("Version check", "couldn't retrieve version from url ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String bodyStr = response.body().string();
            try {
                JSONObject bodyJson = new JSONObject(bodyStr);
                if (bodyJson.has("versioncode")) {
                    int curLiveVersion = bodyJson.getInt("versioncode");
                    Log.i("Version check", String.valueOf(curLiveVersion));
                    PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
                    int oldVersion = packageInfo.versionCode;
                    if (oldVersion < curLiveVersion) {
                        //TODO
                        Log.i("Version check", "new version found , please update");
                        String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
                        Looper.prepare();
                        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Update Found");
                        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName + "&hl=en"));
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                        progressDialog.show();
                        Looper.loop();
                    } else {
                        Log.i("Version check", "new version not available");
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException | NumberFormatException | PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Test-

1. Create [Internal testing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internal-testing/) in developer console . Add tester by email , upload a signed build and share the link to user, in tester side accept the invitation . Tester will uninstall public version and install beta test version .
2. Build another app with grater version code and create another internal testing and upload new build . In this case do not share link with tester . Wait few hours and check *from tester device* in Playstore search that the latest version actually live or not (actually cache issue still have or not) if live then edit the gist . Suppose your latest app build with versioncode 2 then give value

   ```
    {
    "versioncode": "2"
    }
   ```
3. If Tester open your App from tester device now , this will ask for force update . But before change the gist your app was usable to your users.

In every production release just take few times , then update the gist .
Using `Jsoup` type implementation can make your app unstable too , because you don't have access to google web , any change from them can make your app unstable/unusable. Hope this will help you . Thanks

Coming from in-app....
[image]